# Vaadin 8 -java - How to download a file from a path in a project

Tags: java, file, download, vaadin8

I'm trying to download a pdf file contained in a folder of my project. I don't know how to do. I'm using vaadin 8 and java

Comment: Vaadin 8 has classes like FileResource, ClassResource, ThemeReseource. It depends on where exectly your file is what is correct to use. E.g. is it in the class path or theme folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FileDownloader` extension for this purpose. The `FileDownloader` is attached to some Component and it takes a `Resource` object which determines how to find the file content:

```
   Button downloadButton = new Button("Download file");
   Resource myResource = createResource();
   FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(myResource);
   fileDownloader.extend(downloadButton);
   layout.add(downloadButton);
```

The `Resource` interface has several implementing types which offer different ways of defining the file. For example, if your file is a part of your theme (placed under your theme folder), you can use `ThemeResource`. You can find more information about different `Resource` types in the documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/application/application-resources/#application.resources.api